# VBA Pass Functions to create Root Finder

Tags: vba, function, root

I am trying to create a generic bissection method root finding user defined function called Root.

I want Root accept the following "arguments"

Root(Function, variable, lower bound, upper bound)

Root(F(a,b,c,...,Z), Z, Upper, Lower)

The Root function accepts the minimizing function with any constants and then one constant which is allowed to be varied by Root.

```
Function Root(ErrorFunction As String, ByRef guess As Single, A As Single, B As Single) As Single

Dim M As Single
Dim Error_A As Single
Dim Error_B As Single
Dim Error_M As Single
Dim Count As Integer
Dim Msg As Integer

A = 0.01
B = 2
M = (A + B) / 2
Error_M = 1
Count = 0

Do While Abs(Error_M / M) > 0.0000000001

    Count = Count + 1
    If Count = 100 Then
        Exit Do
        Msg = MsgBox("Did not Converge", vbOK, "Error: Convergence")
    End If
    Error_A = ErrorFunction(A)
    Error_B = ErrorFunction(B)
    Error_M = ErrorFunction(M)

        If Sgn(Error_A) = Sgn(Error_M) Then
            A = M
        End If

        If Sgn(Error_M) = Sgn(Error_B) Then
            B = M
        End If
    M = (A + B) / 2
Loop
Root = M
End Function

Function TestErrorFunction(T As Single, P As Single, Z As Single, Gas_Comp As Range) As Single

Dim Tr As Single
Dim Pr As Single
Tr = T_Reduced(T, Gas_Comp)
Pr = P_Reduced(P, Gas_Comp)
Dim Temp As Single
Dim A
A = Array(0.3265, -1.07, -0.5339, 0.01569, -0.05165, 0.5475, -0.7361, 0.1844, 0.1056, 0.6134, 0.721)

Temp = 0.27 * Pr / (Z * Tr)
TestErrorFunction = 1 - Z + (A(0) + A(1) / Tr + A(2) / Tr ^ 3 + A(3) / Tr ^ 4 + A(4) / Tr ^ 5) * Temp + (A(5) + A(6) / Tr + A(7) / Tr ^ 2) * Temp ^ 2 - A(8) * (A(6) / Tr + A(7) / Tr ^ 2) * Temp ^ 5 + A(9) * Temp ^ 2 / Tr ^ 3 * (1 + A(10) * Temp ^ 2) * Exp(-A(10) * Temp ^ 2)

End Function
```

Comment: Pass function name as string, call with `Application.Run`.